# CAML Query error when more than 2 variables in OR

Tags: sharepoint, caml

In my SharePoint CAML query, when filtering with two input, it is successful. However, when I have 3 or more, it failed.

Is there a different format to be used when using more than two inputs?

---

**Pass (2 fields):**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Or>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value></Eq>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value></Eq>
        </Or>
            <Neq><FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value></Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

---

**Fail (3 fields):**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Or>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value></Eq>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value></Eq>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H3</Value></Eq>
        </Or>
            <Neq><FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value></Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

---

**Error:**

> Cannot complete this action. Please try again. at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient
>   pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName,
>   String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData() at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Count()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CAML syntax, both `<Or>` and `<And>` and *binary* operators. Hence they must have two operands only. If you need more, you have to nest them accordingly. In your case:

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Or>
            <Or>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value></Eq>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value></Eq>
            </Or>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H3</Value></Eq>
        </Or>
        <Neq><FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value></Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```